# Select certain slides by check boxes in Power Point VBA

Tags: vba, checkbox, slideshow, powerpoint

I need to be able to create a new `.ppt` (PowerPoint presentation) from selected slides in my original `.ppt`. The following macro will take whatever slides you currently have selected and copy them into a new `.ppt`. I've found the following nice code to do most of the work.

```
Private Sub NytPPT_Click()

'PURPOSE: Copies selected slides and pastes them into a brand new presentation file
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim NewPPT As Presentation
Dim OldPPT As Presentation
Dim Selected_slds As SlideRange
Dim Old_sld As Slide
Dim New_sld As Slide
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim myArray() As Long
Dim SortTest As Boolean

'Set variable to Active Presentation
  Set OldPPT = ActivePresentation

'Set variable equal to only selected slides in Active Presentation
  Set Selected_slds = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange

'Sort Selected slides via SlideIndex
  'Fill an array with SlideIndex numbers
    ReDim myArray(1 To Selected_slds.Count)
      For y = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        myArray(y) = Selected_slds(y).SlideIndex
      Next y

  'Sort SlideIndex array
    Do
      SortTest = False
      For y = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray) - 1
        If myArray(y) > myArray(y + 1) Then
          Swap = myArray(y)
          myArray(y) = myArray(y + 1)
          myArray(y + 1) = Swap
          SortTest = True
        End If
      Next y
    Loop Until Not SortTest

'Set variable equal to only selected slides in Active Presentation (in numerical order)
  Set Selected_slds = OldPPT.Slides.Range(myArray)

'Create a brand new PowerPoint presentation
  Set NewPPT = Presentations.Add

'Align Page Setup
  NewPPT.PageSetup.SlideHeight = OldPPT.PageSetup.SlideHeight
  NewPPT.PageSetup.SlideOrientation = OldPPT.PageSetup.SlideOrientation
  NewPPT.PageSetup.SlideSize = OldPPT.PageSetup.SlideSize
  NewPPT.PageSetup.SlideWidth = OldPPT.PageSetup.SlideWidth

'Loop through slides in SlideRange
  For x = 1 To Selected_slds.Count

    'Set variable to a specific slide
      Set Old_sld = Selected_slds(x)

    'Copy Old Slide
      yy = Old_sld.SlideIndex
      Old_sld.Copy

    'Paste Slide in new PowerPoint
      NewPPT.Slides.Paste
      Set New_sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

    'Bring over slides design
      New_sld.Design = Old_sld.Design

    'Bring over slides custom color formatting
      New_sld.ColorScheme = Old_sld.ColorScheme

    'Bring over whether or not slide follows Master Slide Layout (True/False)
      New_sld.FollowMasterBackground = Old_sld.FollowMasterBackground

  Next x


End Sub
```

What I need to do, is to select which slides to copy - based on check boxes. So, for example if I select Check Box 1 = TRUE, it will create slides 1, 2 and 3. Or if I select Check box 2 = TRUE, that it could select slide 3, 4, 5 and 6. And so, if I selected both boxes it would create slides = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. Leaving out any duplicates.

I've tried a lot, including this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(1, 2, 3)).Select
    Else
        MsgBox "nothing"
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(3, 4, 5, 6)).Select
    Else
        MsgBox "nothing"
    End If
End Sub
```

I get the error: Slide (unknown member) : Invalid request. This view does not support selection.

I am not sure how I could get this to work? Any help is appreciated, I'am very new to VBA coding.

All credit for code goes to. http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/3/copy-selected-slides-into-new-powerpoint-presentation

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the view to enabled the slides to be selected as follows:

```
ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlideSorter
```

For some reason, the slides aren't selected in the normal view!

But selecting things in PowerPoint brings its own challenges (as seen with the view type) and you don't need to select them in order to copy and paste them as per this example:

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides
  .Range(Array(1, 2)).Copy
  .Paste
End With
```

This will simplify your code as you don't need to manage windows and their views.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good - but I still don't quite understand how to use it with checkboxes?

Comment: Where are these checkbox controls? On a form or ActiveX content on slides? If on a slide, I wouldn't recommend using them as they lead to verbose security warnings (and Mac incompatibility if that's a consideration). It would be better to assign your CheckBoxX_Click macros to a shape on a slide via Insert / Action / Mouse Click / Run Macro